# Angular4: unexpected app refresh with @ViewChild()

Tags: angular, dom, data-binding, viewchild

I'm trying to get the value of an input field via @ViewChild(). However, even though it seems to work, this method triggered unexpected refresh into the app:

-app refreshes right after clicking the button trigerring the event

-app refreshes once when navigating through the app whith a navbar

template:

```
<input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" #nameInput>
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="addShop()">Add</button>
<p>{{shopName}}</p>
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shopping-edit',
  templateUrl: './shopping-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shopping-edit.component.css']
})
export class ShoppingEditComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('nameInput') shopName:ElementRef;
@ViewChild('amountInput') shopAmount:ElementRef;

coucou:string;


addShop(){
    this.shopName = this.shopName.nativeElement.value;
}

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Remove type="submit" in the button, just replace it for type="button"

Comment: Because your button type is set to `submit`. Also, why are using `ViewChild`? Seeing from your code you can just bind your element to `ngModel`

Comment: It's just for the sake of an exercice to learn Angular4. I will later have to pass this information down to other component. The string interpolation is just a quick way to check that I get the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When button type is submit inside a `form`, on form `submit` event it tries to hit `action`(attribute) provided on form level. If there is no action attribute on `form`, it refreshes the page. To stop this behaviour you could change button `type` to `button`(just by removing `type` attribute wouldn't fix issue, implicitly button has `submit` type).

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="addShop()">Add</button>
```

---

In angular world you should be using `(ngSumbit)="submit()"` event on `form` level then you can keep your button type as `submit`. Behind the scene form event gets suppressed by `ngSubmit` event. You can make ajax call from your function specified on `ngSubmit` event.

**Markup**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="addShop()" #heroForm="ngForm">
  <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control">
  <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Add</button>
  <p>{{shopName}}</p> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove type="submit" in the button, just replace it for type="button"

Change the following line:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" (click)="addShop()">Add</button>
```

to:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" type="button" (click)="addShop()">Add</button>
```

The browser thinks you're submitting a form, that's why it refreshes the page